# Laravel: Repeating Fields (and Field Groups): Form Model Binding

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel

I am building a form in Laravel that deals with an array field in the form of repeatable entities (whether it be single inputs or field groups). I am running into an issue using Form Model Binding when there is either a validation error with a repeated field or a different input in the form.

Right now I'm generating new "instances" of each field by pulling in the view partial with AJAX

```
# Add Feature
$(document).on 'click', '.js-listing__add-feature', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $.ajax
    url: dashboard.partials.feature
    type: 'GET'
    success: (data) ->
      $data = $(data)
      $('.js-listing__features').append $data
      return
  return

# Removing features
$(document).on 'click', '.js-listing__remove-feature', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).parent('.js-listing__feature-wrapper').remove()
  return
```

So, a user can create new feature inputs on the fly which ultimately combine into an array when saved. The issue becomes when there is a validation issue in the form and we are redirected back. I have not found a way to access the features array in the state it was in (dynamic or not) to spit out what they previously had. In writing this, I guess the issue also becomes clearing out that field if it was the input itself causing the validation issue.

I've searched around in the docs and the 'ole Google for inspiration on this topic, but haven't come across anything. Any nudges in the right direction would be extremely helpful. Thanks as always!

## Example of form

```
@extends('dashboard.master')

@section('content')
    <h1>Edit Listing</h1>

    @include('dashboard.partials.errors')

    {!! Form::model($listing, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['dashboard.listings.update', $listing->id], 'class' => 'uk-form']) !!}
    <div class="uk-form-row">
        {!! Form::label('price', 'Price') !!}
        {!! Form::text('price') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row js-listing__features">
        {!! Form::label('features', 'Features') !!}
        @if ($listing->features && count($listing->features))
            @foreach($listing->features as $key => $feature)
                <div class="js-listing__feature-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" name="features[]" value="{{$feature}}">
                    <a class="js-listing__add-feature" href="#">+</a>
                    @if ($key >  0)
                        <a class="js-listing__remove-feature" href="#">-</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <div class="js-listing__feature-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="features[]">
                <a class="js-listing__add-feature" href="#">+</a>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row">
        {!! Form::submit('Update Listing') !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

You'll see my take on what I'd do for the `@foreach` when I have values to display them when editing the listing. The issue here is not reading the values back (I have set/get attributes working fine for those), but how Form Model Binding works with input arrays so I can still have those values available when they have been dynamically added to the form with AJAX.

Comment: can you please give an example of how your form looks like and where exactly you are facing issues ?

Comment: Sure @DhirajBodicherla I've added the form example in my original question. Thanks!

Comment: If you can show it on fiddle or some where else then it will be more easy to solve your problem.

Comment: Not sure how I could show a fiddle with server-side technologies behind a framework like Laravel...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some times ago... My code is surely not very elegant, but it worked ; it may help you to build something...

My trick was to generate a different name for items, distinguish old and new items, count new items:

```
<input type="text" name="E1-features"> // existing feature #1
<input type="text" name="N1-features"> // new feature #1
<input type="text" name="N3-features"> // new feature #3 (assuming user deleted #2)
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="3"> // 3 features were added
```

Server side, the controller distinguishes the existing inputs from the new ones. Here is the code for the new inputs:

```
Input::flash();

// Existing features
foreach($features as $key => $feature){
    if (Input::get('E'.$key.'-features')){
        $rules['E'.$key.'-features'] = 'required';
    }
}

// New features
for ($i = 1;  $i <= Input::get('counter'); $i++) {
    if (Input::get('N'.$i.'-features')){
        $rules['N'.$i.'-features'] = 'required';
    }
}

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::to('page')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}else{
   // data stuff
}
```